# C# Linq List in other list

Tags: c#, linq, set, union

I have 2 string lists `List<string>`

```
 listA
 listB
```

I need to know if all of `listB` is in `listA`. `listA` is the bigger list and we need to make sure all of `listB` is in it.

Is that a Union?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a union. The simplest approach is to check whether there's anything in `listB` which *isn't* in `listA`:

```
var result = !listB.Except(listA).Any();
```

In other words, if you took everything from `listA` away from `listB`, would there be anything left or not?

Or of course you could do it more explicitly:

```
// Optional: makes the Contains check quicker.
var setA = new HashSet<string>(setA);
var result = listB.All(setA.Contains);
```